# Phase diagram on matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to make a phase diagram for a parameter sweep experiment. The parameters are as follows:

```
vmax_values = [1, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15]
cost_values = [0.001, 0.0025, 0.005, 0.0075, 0.01, 0.025, 0.05]
```

As you can see, the second set of variables are not evenly spaced. Now, I want to make a phase diagram that shows the outcome of the experiment with particular parameter combinations.

```py
import json
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
import numpy as np

json_file_path = 'D:/cost_pc/output/results.json'

with open(json_file_path, 'r') as json_file:
    results_dict = json.load(json_file)

cmap = ListedColormap(['green', 'cyan', 'red'])

vmax_values = [1, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15]
cost_values = [0.001, 0.0025, 0.005, 0.0075, 0.01, 0.025, 0.05]

desired_replicate_number = 4

vmax_list, cost_list, result_list = [], [], []

vmax_categorical = np.arange(len(vmax_values))
cost_categorical = np.arange(len(cost_values))

for i, vmax in enumerate(vmax_values):
    for j, cost in enumerate(cost_values):
        vmax_list.append(vmax_categorical[i])
        cost_list.append(cost_categorical[j])

        # Get the result for the desired replicate number
        result = results_dict.get(f"p_vmax_{vmax}_cost_{cost}", {}).get(str(desired_replicate_number), None)
        if result == "Cheater victory":
            result_list.append(1)  # cheater Victory
        elif result == "Broadcaster victory":
            result_list.append(2)  # broadcaster Victory
        elif result == "Coexistence":
            result_list.append(0)  # coexistence
        else:
            result_list.append(-1)  

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
scatter = plt.scatter(cost_list, vmax_list, c=result_list, cmap=cmap, s=150, marker='o', edgecolors='k')

plt.xlabel('Cost', fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel('Vmax', fontsize=16)
plt.title(f'Phase Diagram (Replicate {desired_replicate_number})', fontsize=18)

plt.xticks(cost_values, ['0.001', '0.0025', '0.005', '0.0075', '0.01', '0.025', '0.05'], rotation='vertical')
plt.yticks(vmax_values, [str(v) for v in vmax_values])

legend_labels = ['Coexistence', 'Cheater Victory', 'Broadcaster Victory']
legend_handles = [plt.Line2D([0], [0], marker='o', color='w', markerfacecolor=cmap(i), markersize=10) for i in range(len(legend_labels))]
plt.legend(legend_handles, legend_labels, loc='upper right')

plt.grid(False)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

This creates a scatter plot, but the values related to the cost variable are clumped on one side of the axis because of the proximity of the values. Is there a way to customize that? I want the diagram to be a reference figure and not have the axis ticks correspond to numerical scales.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Your question doesn't show the current plot and we cannot reproduce the plot since we do not have the data you used. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which is the shortest possible code necessary to show the issue.

Comment: if you don't show us a picture of what you want as a result (made with an image editor) we can only guess what you mean

Comment: when is `vmax_categorical[i] != i`, same for `cost_categorical[j] != j`

Comment: you have a great problem keeping the consistency of colors, labels, colors_index maintainable, for 3 items it already is hard to see if it is correct

Answer (score 0):

based on what you write you might need to use:

```py
plt.xticks(cost_categorical, ['0.001', '0.0025', '0.005', '0.0075', '0.01', '0.025', '0.05'], rotation='vertical')
```

The positions of the labels need to match the values of the xcoords used in the scatterplot.